# Laravel, use auth and auth.basic

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I've got a website with an 'admin dashboard'. I would like to limit access to the admin dashboard with the auth.basic filter in Laravel.

But the site itself also has an account system, and I would like to use the 'normal' auth filter for that.

Is it possible to use those two filters seperate from each other, but on the same website?

Answer (score 0):

Use groups and define other routes inside them.

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin', 'before'=>'auth.basic'], function(){
    Route::get('/', function(){});
});

Route::group(['prefix'=>'account', 'before'=>'auth.account'], function(){
    Route::get('/', function(){});
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but if you do it this way, doesn't it mean that if some logs in there 'account' they're also logged in for the admin part of the website?

Comment: It depends on your auth system. I would use roles (user types) for users and check if user's role is allowed. For example `auth.account` would check, if user's role is `customer` or something. Take a look at Authority package https://github.com/machuga/authority-l4